# XCom for S3KeySensor matches

Tags: airflow

I'm building my first Airflow DAG that watches an S3 bucket for new files and triggers a REST API call for each match, passing the S3 key as an argument of the API call.

This is my first draft:

```py
from datetime import datetime

from airflow.models.dag import DAG
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3 import S3KeySensor
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator


with DAG(
    dag_id="htj2k_convert",
    schedule="@once",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["drs", "media-proc"],
) as dag:

    sensor = S3KeySensor(
        task_id="imgconv_watcher",
        bucket_key="master/*.jp2",
        bucket_name="imgconv-dev",
        wildcard_match=True,
        aws_conn_id="s3_conn",
    )

    processor = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id="imgconv_processor",
        http_conn_id="imgconv_http_conn",
        endpoint="/convert/image/jp2_htj2k",
        method="POST",
        data={"ref": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='imgconv_watcher') }}"},
    )

    sensor >> processor
```

There are a few  obvious problems with this, chiefly that the HTTP operator is passing `None` to the HTTP call. In the [XCom documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html#xcoms) I read that the return value of the upstream is used by default, but I am not sure if and how the list of matching files is passed.

The other problem is that I want the HTTP operator to be fired for each of the matches, possibly in parallel, and I can't find any reference in the documentation about whether and how this can be done.

S3 sensor log:

```
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=htj2k_convert/run_id=manual__2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00/task_id=imgconv_watcher/attempt=1.log
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: htj2k_convert.imgconv_watcher manual__2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: htj2k_convert.imgconv_watcher manual__2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(S3KeySensor): imgconv_watcher> on 2023-08-09 20:25:27.349582+00:00
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 274 to run task
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'htj2k_convert', 'imgconv_watcher', 'manual__2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00', '--job-id', '88', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/htj2k_convert.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpibmrsebv']
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 88: Subtask imgconv_watcher
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: htj2k_convert.imgconv_watcher manual__2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00 [running]> on host 9b4296aca57e
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1547} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='***' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='htj2k_convert' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='imgconv_watcher' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-08-09T20:25:27.349582+00:00'
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {s3.py:99} INFO - Poking for key : s3://imgconv-dev/master/*.jp2
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 's3_conn' for task execution.
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {credentials.py:1123} INFO - Found credentials in environment variables.
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {base.py:255} INFO - Success criteria met. Exiting.
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=htj2k_convert, task_id=imgconv_watcher, execution_date=20230809T202527, start_date=20230809T202529, end_date=20230809T202529
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-08-09, 20:25:29 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but in the details panel for the S3 sensor task I see the `output` value is set to `{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='imgconv_watcher', dag_id='htj2k_convert', key='return_value') }}`.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am working in a docker-compose environment where the S3 server (minio) is at `http://s3:9000`. I set up a specific connectin with that URL. I am not sure if the log message `Poking for key : s3://imgconv-dev/master/*.jp2` resolves the `s3:` bit into the actual connection's address (I imagine it would fail otherwise?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3KeySensor is finishig (successful) once the condition you set occured. it does not returns in the xcom the list of files that applyied the condition.

once the sensor finished you need to create another task that gets the list of files accoeding same condition (using boto3 or S3Hook). this task should return a list that you can use for the SimpleHttpOperator dynamicly and in parallel using [Airflow Dynmic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html) capability

here a simple example (why simple ? because it take all files from the folder after sensor returns True) :

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3 import S3KeySensor
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3 import S3ListOperator
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator

with DAG(
        dag_id="htj2k_convert",
        schedule_interval="@once",
        start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["drs", "media-proc"],
) as dag:
    @task
    def create_data(ti: TaskInstance = None):
        return [{"ref" : val} for val in ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="imgconv_list")] # here we create json for each value (file) in the list


    sensor = S3KeySensor(
        task_id="imgconv_watcher",
        bucket_key="master/*.jp2",
        bucket_name="imgconv-dev",
        wildcard_match=True,
        aws_conn_id="s3_conn",
    )

    imgconv_list = S3ListOperator(task_id="imgconv_list", bucket="imgconv-dev", prefix="master/")

    processor = SimpleHttpOperator.partial(
        task_id="imgconv_processor",
        http_conn_id="imgconv_http_conn",
        endpoint="/convert/image/jp2_htj2k",
        method="POST",
    ).expand(data=create_data())

    sensor >> imgconv_list >> processor
```

[image]

Comment: I see. First get the notification that something new was added to the bucket, then list the keys, then use `.expand()` on the list generating function to act on the individual keys. Thanks!

Comment: I think you meant `bucket="imgconv-dev"` as an argument for the S3Listperator.

Comment: I fixed it. I debugged it with values from my env and then changed it to yours

Comment: Thank you. One other question: how does `create_data()` get its `ti` value? I tried a similar DAG with some slight variations, but by the time it gets to `create_data()` the XCom is empty.

Comment: When you put the task decorator airflow inject  the context that its actually a dict with ti dag_run and more. You can also use get_current_context function inside the functuon to get the context and from it to get the task instance

Comment: Maybe it's something that changed very recently, but I couldn't get to the XCom from the task instance that was passed to `create_data()`.They would always be empty. After some more digging into the documentation, I got it to work by passing `imgconv_list.output` to `create_data()` in the expand call and changing the signature of the latter by accepting the XCom value directly. Thanks.